# How to directly use files stored in cloud on my local software which is not cloud native software

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud, onedrive, microsoft365, tally

I have a requirement and I am not able to find something related to this on the internet (yeah bit strange!!)

I have some software in my local machine that I use for my work (some finance software for tax filing, and maintaining balance sheets like Tally). I have some people working with me as well and we all want to share the data files and work on the same files. We earlier used the local network cloud (NAS) which allowed us to work on shared files as the local cloud used to appear as a hard drive in our laptop and our software could point to that drive and use the files. This way we were able to share files across multiple systems. But it was risky as there is no backup outside this cloud.

Now, we want to move to an actual cloud storage like Microsoft one drive, Google Drive and still be able to use and share the common files in our software. The problem is we don't know how to configure my software to use the files directly from the cloud (or is it even possible).

We know there are ways like syncing a folder with the cloud and we can point our software to put the data in that local machine folder which will be synced with the cloud. But we don't want people to have data in their local. We need software to use the files directly from the cloud, work over them and save them back to the cloud directly.

Is it possible to do without having a copy of data in local machine?

Thanks in Advance for the help!!!

Comment: Why don't you use [Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/13022292)? This tool will help you sync with Google Drive, and keeping the files like if they were in a local storage in the PC.